# Variation in Pointer address values

Tags: c, pointers

I tested a small program which is written below.My question is why there is a 12 bytes difference between the pointer to a value and a pointer to the first pointer.But if you look at other pointer addresses there is only a difference of 8 bytes every time.I executed this program multiple times and always I see this difference.Can anyone explain me what could be the reason?Thanks in advance..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
        int val;
        int *ptr;
        int **ptrptr;
        int ***ptrptrptr;
        int ****ptrptrptrptr;
        int *****ptrptrptrptrptr;

        val=10;
        ptr=&val;
        ptrptr=&ptr;
        ptrptrptr=&ptrptr;
        ptrptrptrptr=&ptrptrptr;
        ptrptrptrptrptr=&ptrptrptrptr;

        printf("Value-%d\n",val);
        printf("Value address - %d\n",ptr);
        printf("Pointer address - %d\n",ptrptr);
        printf("Pointer Pointer Address -%d\n",ptrptrptr);
        printf("Pointer Pointer Pointer Address -%d\n",ptrptrptrptr);
        printf("Pointer Pointer Pointer Pointer Address -%d\n",ptrptrptrptrptr);

        return 0;
}
```

The results are:

```
Value-10
Value address - -1308521884
Pointer address - -1308521896
Pointer Pointer Address --1308521904
Pointer Pointer Pointer Address --1308521912
Pointer Pointer Pointer Pointer Address --1308521920
```

Comment: Whay compiler, what linker, what processor?  32 or 64-bit? What is an int - how big is it?  Does it really matter much?  I mean, how did you even notice?

Comment: It's interesting that changing the first int to long works as you expect.

Comment: Ya its working good for long... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just the stack layout your compiler chose, f.e. it could be for alignment reasons. Things would most likely still work with other layouts.

Side note, you should use `%p` to print addresses.

Comment: Yes %p is converting the int address into hexa..hope I am correct.. but still whats the reason for stack taking address like that...

Comment: @Vutukuri The stack layout isn't fixed in stone, nor is it standard. Each compiler has absolute freedom in choosing how to arrange local variables. Passing arguments is another story (`cdecl`, `stdcall`).

Comment: Okay so u mean to say if I execute the same program on a diff compiler I might get diff results?

Comment: @Vutukuri Yup. Also, you might get different results by simply changing the switches - for example optimization flags.

Comment: @Vutukuri: if you use `%p`, then you must cast your pointer to `void*`. If you want to print an integral value, you can also cast to `uintptr_t` and use the appropriate macro from `stdint.h`.